# Windows 10 Fast Boot Disable Error

Tags: windows-10

I would like to dual boot my computer with Kali Linux. I want to go to the boot menu to boot my usb to install Kali Linux. But when I restart or shutdown and power on my computer, it boots directly into Windows. So I thought that I may need to disable fastboot. But even after disabling Fast Boot in power options my computer does fastboot. So I couldn't access the boot manager menu to boot to my usb flash drive for the dual booting process. I searched the web but no help. Anything I can do?

Comment: What motherboard do you have?

Comment: Satellite C850 Thats my motherboard

Comment: Boot into BIOS and then boot off of the USB stick. The boot manager doesn't appear until after the installation is complete.

Comment: Explain how to boot into BIOS

Comment: Try pressing `Del` or `F2`

Comment: My problem is i couldn't disable fast boot mode.Even if i disable it,it fast boots.So i cannot press DEL or F2

Comment: Try removing the CMOS battery and then try to go to BIOS.

Comment: Disable hibernation in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things here.

Within Windows FastBoot is Windows hibernating your operating system in order to boot faster.

The second FastBoot is a UEFI feature that skips a lot of pre-boot checks and proceeds to boot the operating system almost instantly. More info at [Ten Forums](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/21284-fast-boot-enable-uefi-firmware-settings-windows-8-10-a.html)

Aggravatingly these features have the same name but are separate and need to be disabled separately.

You need to find out how to boot into your UEFI (check your motherboard manual) and disable *that* fast boot.

Disabling Windows FastBoot at the same time is a good idea as corruption can occur if you try to access files from a hibernated system from an alternative OS.